# Nginx config to make request from one server, then another (FE then BE)

Tags: nginx

Is there an easy way to configure nginx to proxy one server, and if that request fails (4xx or 5xx) try another server?

```
GET /index.html

-> try backend dev server -> 404 not found
-> try front-end dev server -> 200 ok!
```

Web apps have a front-end and back-end.  I'm working with [Quasar SPA front-end](https://v1.quasar-framework.org/quasar-cli/installation#How-it-works) and a [FeathersJS Node back-end](https://docs.feathersjs.com/guides/basics/starting.html).

In production, the back-end serves a built copy of the front-end.

In development, the front-end server is rebuilding and hot-loading separate from the back-end.

Is there an easy way to configure nginx to proxy one server, and if that request fails (4xx or 5xx) try another server?

Thanks!